# How to make my question to be still in use?

Tags: discussion

I had a question about 3DS Max and there was a misunderstanding and it was migrated from "graphicdesign.stackexchange" to blender.stackexchange". I updated it and now I don't know what to do.

It looked like I'm asking "how to render the view-port in Blender like it is in 3DS Max?". What I meant was "How to render the view-port in 3DS Max as it is?". Because in blender you can render edges and such and I asked how to do the same in 3DS Max.

Can the question be "un-migrated"? Or what do I have to do to fix things?

Here is the question - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15206/is-there-a-way-to-render-the-view-port-as-it-is-in-3ds-max?noredirect=1#comment21171_15206

Comment: I didn't know where to ask, so I asked here and if anybody can point me to where to ask about issues like this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest clarity in further questions.  In no way were we to know that you meant 3DS Max.  If you want it on GD I would flag for a moderator attention and inform them on your mistake **on Blender** to have it migrated in regards to it being off-topic now.

Furthermore, I would add that you should take care in how you ask your questions because now there are two good answers from members that took time out to help you which are associated to your question that are now useless.

We have tried to work with you the best we can.  I apologize up front that we don't have the level of 3DS Max members that could help you but you need to help yourself and ask better questions that show effort and clarity.

### Edit:

Thinking more on the issue..  I would advise you to edit it for Blender and **leave it on Blender** and I say that for several reasons because you will possibly end up annoying the community at Blender which may cause your questions not to be answered in future circumstances.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Do I have to update the question to be about blender or I should update it on what I meant in the first place?

Comment: That's up to you.  Personally I would edit for Blender and leave it.  Some good answers there but in all reality I hope you learn something from this.  Your level of effort and clarity are crucial to good answers because at this time we aren't mind readers.

Comment: The question was "How to render the view-port as it is in 3DS Max? The thing that was missing was a comma next to "in". I'll be more careful in the future. And again, thanks.